# Eigenvectors of positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-matrices

Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix with positive coefficients. How can we prove that:

- There exists a positive eigenvector $v>0$ (all $v_i>0$) associated with the greates-absolute-value eigenvalue $\lambda^*$, i.e $\ $ $|\lambda^*|\ge |\lambda_i| \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \lambda_i \in \sigma (A)$
- This is a unique (up to positive multiples) positive eigenvector. In other words, there are no positive eigenvectors for $A$ other than $v$ and its positive multiples.

Comment: positive eigenvector $v>0$ means what??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

Comment: It means all $v_i>0$